# Overrideing devise route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
  as :user do
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

I want to be able to add `get 'register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration`,
 but notice how above code skips only `:sessions`

I tried doing `:skip => [:sessions, :registrations]`, but it does not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does ``rake routes`` outputs when skipping both :sessions and :registrations and adding ``get 'register' => 'devise/registrations#new'``?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bcEGhGqV ... seems like it should work, but it throws me errors  `NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions,:registrations ]
  as :user do
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    post 'users' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get 'register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
  end
```

The problem has been fixed by including `post 'users'....`
as I believe rails makes sure that all functions such as `registrations#create` does not end up in a dead end. I am not too too sure, but it looks like it checks dependencies of each func.